# Dialogflw project location and laguange selected

Tags: actions-on-google

Dialogflw project has the location and laguange selected properly, but the error mensage show up when I try open Action on Google console.

I try it solve the problem in many ways, but it doesn’t work.

Failed to upload action package to AOG (preview)
Request contains an invalid argument.
Locale pt-br was selected but the language pt-BR has not been selected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpaRN.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNyXa.jpg)

Comment: Can you update your question to include screen shots of the language and intent configurations in the Dialogflow console?

Comment: Thank's Prisoner! It's here